# How do I increment a value for an uninitialized key in a hash?

Tags: ruby, hashtable

If I try to increment the value for a key that does not yet exist in a hash like so

```
h = Hash.new
h[:ferrets] += 1
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

This makes sense to me, and I know this must be an incredibly easy question, but I'm having trouble finding it on SO. How do I add and increment such keys if I don't even know in advance what keys I will have?

Comment: The answers give the normal ways of handling this situation, but you should also be aware that you could simply write: `if h.has_key?(:ferrets); h[:ferrets] += 1; else h[:ferrets] = 1; end`.  The method [Hash#has_key?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) has, not one, not two, but three aliases (i.e., any can be used): `key?`, `include?` and `member?`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can set default value of hash in constructor

```
h = Hash.new(0)
h[:ferrets] += 1
p h[:ferrets]
```

note that setting default value has some pitfalls, so you must use it with care.

```
h = Hash.new([]) # does not work as expected (after `x[:a].push(3)`, `x[:b]` would be `[3]`)
h = Hash.new{[]} # also does not work as expected (after `x[:a].push(3)`  `x[:a]` would be `[]` not `[3]`)
h = Hash.new{Array.new} # use this one instead
```

Therefore using `||=` might be simple in some situations

```
h = Hash.new
h[:ferrets] ||= 0
h[:ferrets] += 1
```

Comment: I liked the ||= solution you gave but deleted quickly. Would you please explain why I would use one over the other? Both the default val solution and the ||= seem good to me.

Comment: Actually, I can think of one reason why I would use ||= instead: if the types of the values mattered and nil was important for sorting out what was uninitialized. The default val version worked well for my situation, though.

Answer (score 8):

One way to fix this is to give your hash a default:

```
h = Hash.new
h.default = 0
h[:ferrets] += 1

puts h.inspect
#{:ferrets=>1}
```

The default default for a hash is nil, and nil doesn't understand how to ++ itself.

```
h = Hash.new{0} 
h = Hash.new(0) # also works (thanks @Phrogz)
```

Is another way to set the default while declaring it.

Comment: Note, no reason to use the block form here. Try `Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: Thanks!  I always learn so much from these types of questions.